# Serial output not as expected

Tags: serial, c++

I have a SIM808 mod that i've connected via serial to a Pi3. With `minicom` or `screen` I communicate to the unit fine. From my code however I do not get the expected results. I used some code that I've found. Here is the code

```
int OpenSerial()
{
    int fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd > 0)
    {

        unsigned char rx_buffer[256];
        int rx_length = read(fd, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);        //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
        if (rx_length < 0)
        {
            //An error occured (will occur if there are no bytes)
        }
        else if (rx_length == 0)
        {
            //No data waiting
        }
        else
        {
            //Bytes received
            rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
            printf("%i BUFFER FLUSHED. Bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx_buffer);
        }
    }
    return fd;
}

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("error %d from tcgetattr", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    tty.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;     //<Set baud rate
    tty.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    tty.c_oflag = 0;
    tty.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void set_blocking(int fd, int should_block)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("error %d from tggetattr", errno);
        return;
    }

    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = should_block ? 1 : 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
        printf("error %d setting term attributes", errno);
}

void EnableGPS()
{
    int fd = OpenSerial(); // open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    set_interface_attribs(fd, B9600, 0);  // set speed to 9,600 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
    set_blocking(fd, 0);                // set no blocking

    unsigned char tx_buffer[20];
    unsigned char *p_tx_buffer;

    p_tx_buffer = &tx_buffer[0];
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'A';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'T';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = '+';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'C';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'G';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'N';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'S';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'P';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'W';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'R';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = '=';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = '1';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = '\n';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = '\0';

    int count = write(fd, &tx_buffer[0], (p_tx_buffer - &tx_buffer[0]));        //Filestream, bytes to write, number of bytes to write
    if (count < 0)
    {
        printf("UART TX error\n");
    }
    printf("%i bytes send : %s\n", count, tx_buffer);

    //write(fd, "AT+CGNSPWR=1\n", 13);           

    delayMicroseconds((13 + 2) * 100);             
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Read up to 255 characters from the port if they are there
            unsigned char rx_buffer[256];
            int rx_length = read(fd, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);        //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
            if (rx_length < 0)
            {
                //An error occured (will occur if there are no bytes)
            }
            else if (rx_length == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Bytes received
                rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
                printf("%i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx_buffer);
                delayMicroseconds(500);
            }
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

When I Call EnableGPS() my output looks like this

```
14 bytes send : AT+CGNSPWR=1

8 bytes read : AT+CGNSP
8 bytes read : WR=1
3 bytes read : K
```

Why does it only read 8 bytes at a time? Is my sleep time to short? Why does it echo my request? In `minicom` I just get an OK back, and that is what I'm expecting.

I've added the OpenSerial because my buffer is not always flushed when I start the program. Is `tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);` not supposed to flush the buffer?

Comment: There was a kernel problem.  Check [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=184451#p1166780) is not the same.

Comment: From what I can see there my version should be fixed `Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
` however I still get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix my problem by increasing my sleep times. So here is for the beginners. To calculate the sleep time between send and receive, you need to understand how long something will take to transmit at respond. I've learned in the last day that it is called bit times.

Each byte takes 10 bit times to transmit or receive. A bit time is calculated at 1 / baud rate (eg. 1 / 115200 = 8.7µs, 8.7 * 10 = 87µs per byte) and at 9600 baud it takes about 1.042ms per byte.

My sleep in my code was (13 + 2) * 100, so the fact that I actually received 8 chars is a miracle. because that equates to +-1.5ms. I've increased this now to (13 + 2) * 2000) just to be safe, and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing seems to be related to [software UART](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) (or mini-UART) implementation. Try disabling Bluetooth by adding `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` to your `config.txt`. This should free the hardware UART `/dev/ttyAMA0` (normally used for Bluetooth) and remap it back to GPIO pins.

If you have BT stack installed, don't forget to disable its UART service:

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

Comment: I've already disabled BT. I've executed the `sudo systemctl disable hciuart` now. Minicom still works fine on `/dev/ttyAMA0` but from the application it doesn't

Comment: @Jaques Here's something else: try calling `set_blocking` with 1 instead of 0. After all, that's what you want, to block until the full response is received.

Comment: Blocking gets the loop stuck probably on the read, and my output stays the same. It seems that there was a kernel problem, but my kernel should be the fixed version :(

Comment: @Jaques You shouldn't get stuck on a `read` if `VTIME` is specified. Can you tell me on which line you really get stuck?

Comment: Gets stuck on the read. Don't know why, but it does

Comment: @Jaques And what happens when you increase `VMIN` above 8?

Comment: Just to confirm. Do you want me to change `tty.c_cc[VMIN] = should_block ? 1 : 0;` to `tty.c_cc[VMIN] = should_block ? 9 : 0;` in my code?

Comment: @Jaques Yes, that was the crazy idea I had. I'm still not sure where does that limit of 8 comes from, since you weren't using the mini-UART which had that bug joan has mentioned.

Comment: I've sorted my problem out anyway. It is timing. My sleep times was to short for the baud rate. It is now quite high for what I would have thought. But fast in human terms. Add that in your answer, and I will accept :)

Comment: @Jaques I'd rather let you write an answer. I don't quite understand how can 0.5s be insufficient, you should be receiving ~500 bytes in that time at 9600 baud.

Comment: The sleep was 1.5ms (1 500 micro seconds), and in the read it was 500 microseconds. It takes about 1ms per byte on 9600 (which I calculated. Didn't think it actually take so long), so I've increased my sleep to 50ms and now I get the information fine

Comment: @Jaques I can see that. What I don't understand is why the `VTIME` timeout of 0.5s didn't work as expected.